# loop add a comma after nth comma using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I feel like this should be a fairly straight forward question, but I cant seem to get it to work.

I have a csv file and I need to add comma after the nth comma in each row.
I believe I have to use gsub to get it to loop.
something like

```
{gsub(/$nth/,/",")}
```

but I don't understand awk well enough to get it to work.

The end goal of my script is to check to see if a word exist and if it does NOT add a comma after the nth comma.

I'm using grep for that part like this:

```
TEST1=$(cat $file | grep 'Sentence Skills')
 if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then
  awk command to add comma after nth comma
 fi
```

If it doesnt exist I need to add a comma after the nth comma to make sure everything lines up correctly

**UPDATE**
to clarify with sample input and output (my apologies, I originally was not going to include the grep if then fi part)

Here is a sample of the csv:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 87,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
```

And this is what I need it to look like:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 87,,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
```

I need to add one comma after the 5th comma if Reading comprehension doesn't exist, then add one comma after the 6th comma if Sentence Skills doesn't exist, then one comma after the 7th comma if College Level Math doesn't exist, then one comma if Elementary algebra doesn't exist.

If any of those do exist, it does not add a comma and skips on to the next one.

Comment: Show us sample input and output please. Both that needs modification and that doesn't.

Comment: is it after nth column or nth comma, since you have mentioned both in your question.

Comment: I have added the input and output need for further clarification. I really just need to know how to add a comma in a csv file after a certain number of commas. I think I can figure out the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it can be a difficult task to solve it with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). Here you have an approach with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). The difference is that I can use a hash, sort it and add items in the middle of an array with `splice`.

```
perl -F',' -lanE '
    BEGIN {
        %h = ( 
            5 => q|Reading Comprehension|,
            6 => q|Sentence Skills|,
            7 => q|College Level Math|,
            8 => q|Elementary Algebra|,
        );  
    };  
    for (sort keys %h) {
        if ($F[$_] !~ m/^$h{$_}/) {
            splice @F, $_, 0, q||;
            ++$_;
        }   
    }
    printf qq|%s,\n|, join q|,|, @F;
' infile
```

The `-F` has same meaning that [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), so I loop over the hash and check if that field number contains the value. If it doesn't match, insert an empty element just before it, and the last `printf` joins all fields with comma. It yields:

```
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 97,Sentence Skills 104,College Level Math 76,Elementary Algebra 115,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,,Elementary Algebra 34,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,,,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
last,first,A00XXXXXX,1888-01-01,2015-05-13,Reading Comprehension 87,,College Level Math 64,Elementary Algebra 114,
```

Comment: so that looks awesome, I don't know perl at all. how do I run this and do I need to install/setup anything on my Linux machine or would it already be built in? and where do I put in the file name I need it to work on and then where the output will go?

Comment: @moore1emu: Give it a try. It's a one-liner, only splited in lines to make it more readable. You can run it from the shell. Note that last line after the single quote has the input file name.